# visual studio 2015, how hot enable combo box for different choices? in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, combobox

i'm learning how to use C# and visual studio, and what i am trying to do is that
for example

## the question

i have coxcomb 1:

when user choose the first option, i want to display to him some specific buttons and 2 combo-boxes.

but when he choose option 2, i want to display different options and 5 combo-boxes, its like i want to have a side page that can change depends on the user choices, so can anyone help me with that?

should i user the property grid?
this is what i have do far

Comment: This really is a design decision for yourself to make - there is no right or wrong answer. Answers may vary according to "technology" used WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net. You could have all controls on one form & enable/disable them as required or even hide the ones that you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what the user chose with an if-statement in the selection changed event of the combobox.

```
if(combobox.SelectedIndex == 0){
    //Do this when the first item is selected
}else{
    //Do this when the second item is selected 
}
```

or you can check the values instead of the indexes depending on how many items you have in your combobox.

To show or hide controls depending on the user input you can change the visibility property of the controls :

```
button1.Visible = false;
button1.Visible = true; //Assuming you use Windows Forms and not WPF
```

But your question is pretty vague, so I can't give a full answer.
There are many ways to do what you want, this is one of them. You have to be more specific to get a better answer.